# Can I start a sentence with "Established in"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, syntactic-analysis

So, I am proofreading a text which starts as follows:

> This is a bank established since 1900 with majority shareholding held
>   by...

I feel like it can be improved.

Can I change it to:

> Established in 1900, this bank's majority of shares is held by ...

As in, would it make sense grammatically?

Is there any other way I can turn it around to make it sound better?

Comment: The term is [dangling modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier). Executive summary: prescriptivists dictate that it must be avoided at all costs, while descriptivists humbly submit that it is a perfectly natural, grammatical, and ubiquitous construction (and not just in English but in a great many languages) that is understood correctly by absolutely everyone including prescriptivists. As with everything in life, know your audience and tailor your writing to it.

Answer (score 5):

You can start a sentence with “Established in”, as long as the subject of your sentence is the thing that is established in the specified time. In this case: if the subject is “this bank”.

Correct: “Established in 1900, this bank has been through a lot. Currently, the majority of its shares is held by …”

Incorrect: “Established in 1900, this bank’s majority of shares is held by …” as this would mean, taken literally, that the majority of shares was somehow established in 1900.

Also possible, however with repetitive “of”: “The majority of shares of this bank, which was established in 1900, is (currently) held by …”

Comment: A more concise wording that still avoids the misplaced modifier: "Established in 1900, this bank (now?) has a majority of shares held by..."  (For clarity, I would insert the *now* if the majority shareholder is different from in 1900.)

Comment: Here we go again. It is blatantly false that the sentence you have labelled "incorrect" would _mean_ that the majority of shares was somehow established in 1900, because meaning does not reside only in the words, but in pragmatic and real-world knowledge as well. If you encountered that sentence in a paper, you would no doubt sneer at it, but you would not misunderstand it, nor probably even have a moment's doubt about it. Therefore, it _means_ what the OP intended it to mean. Of course, stylistically it is better avoided precisely because pedants will judge you for writing it.

Comment: Colin Fine, to accomodate your philosophical take on meaning, I have changed “this would mean” into “this would mean, taken literally”. The original poster is clearly interested in grammatically correct sentences, since he asked “would it make sense grammatically?”

Comment: The OP's situation is especially delicate because the OP may be proofreading text written by someone else. As a writer I would deeply resent a proofreader's alteration that established a formally false association between a subject and a modifying phrase. Disarming pedantic sneerers might be part of my motivation in structuring sentences carefully; but a much larger part of it is my sense that, by specifying the formally true association between subject and modifier, I accurately identify the underlying pragmatic, real-world relationship instead of requiring my readers to perform that task.

Answer (score 1):

"Established in 1900..." is fine.

It makes perfect sense and is grammatical.